# iOS: AVFoundation Barcode Scanning - change scanning area

Tags: ios, avfoundation, barcode-scanner

I'm using AVFoundation in order to implement barcode scanning. It works well, but I want to decide in which area the barcode has to be centered (for example on the top of the screen). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the rectOfInterest on your AVCaptureMetaDataOutput instance:

```
self.metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = [self.previewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:myRectOfInterest];
```

Comment: And what do you use ad "myrectofinterest". What is the coord system etc? (I am stuck on this problem since long time. I found other docs but I wanna know what you use)